# Two identically-sized elements with position: absolute. Yet they don't superpose perfectly

Tags: css, width, overlap, absolute

I made 2 seemingly identical blocks that contain images. I want to make both blocks superpose eachother perfectly in order to later add some hover-transitions. So I gave a "position: absolute" to one of the blocks, but for some reason it doesn't superpose exactly and seems to have a different width. Do you know why?

Here is the exact place: 
http://www.ways2worldpeace.org/#the-projects

Thank you so much!!

Comment: exact place ? a whole website?

Comment: The #the-projects hashtag should lead to the exact place... 3 circular green icons under a title "The Projects"

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: ok, I understand. Sorry for the bad practice.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATED**

ok create a new class for example "balancer"
and put this content

```
.balancer{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

then you just need to add the speakers to the two divs inside wpb_wrapper

Comment: So that fixes the problem ?

Comment: I tried it with the debug of google chrome and it works well later

Comment: Thank you for your help! But unfortunately, it just makes the "position:fixed"  block disappear in the background at some totally other place in the website...

Comment: updated, try this. I'm sorry for the first time, I ran it and I did not notice the mistake